# What is the purpose of std::forward()'s rvalue reference overload?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, perfect-forwarding

I'm experimenting with Perfect Forwarding and I found that 
[`std::forward()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) needs two overloads:

Overload nr. 1:

```
template <typename T>
inline T&& forward(typename 
std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Overload nr.2:

```
template <typename T>
inline T&& forward(typename 
std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
              "Can not forward an rvalue as an lvalue.");
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Now a typical scenario for Perfect Forwarding is something like

```
template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& e)
{
    wrapped(forward<T>(e));
}
```

Of course you know that when `wrapper()` is instantiated, `T` depends on whether the argument passed to it is an lvalue or an rvalue. If it's an lvalue of type `U`, `T` is deduced to `U&`. If it's an rvalue, `T` is deduced to `U`.

In any case - in the scope of `wrapper()` - `e` is an lvalue, therefore it always uses the first overload of `std::forward()`.

Now my question:

**What is a valid scenario in which the 2nd overload is used (and is needed)?**

Comment: This language is going mad.

Comment: In the case where the argument is not an lvalue. Say, `std::forward<int>(2)`.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: sure, but I can't immagine when a such use is needed

Comment: Define "valid scenario." It seems to me that the `static_assert` is there to prevent malformed usage of the API, not to cover a "valid scenario".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The design rationale for `forward` is discussed in great detail in [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html).

This document lays out 6 use cases:

> A. **Should forward an lvalue as an lvalue.** All implementations pass
>   this test. But this is not the classic perfect forwarding pattern. The
>   purpose of this test is to show that implementation 2 fails in its
>   stated goal of preventing all use cases except perfect forwarding.
>
> B. **Should forward an rvalue as an rvalue.** Like use case A, this is
>   an identity transformation and this presents a motivating example
>   where the identity transformation is needed.
>
> C. **Should *not* forward an rvalue as an lvalue.** This use case
>   demonstrates a dangerous situation of accidentally creating a dangling
>   reference.
>
> D.  **Should forward less cv-qualified expressions to more
>   cv-qualified expressions.** A motivating use case involving the
>   addition of const during the forward.
>
> E. **Should forward expressions of derived type to an accessible,
>   unambiguous base type.** A motivating use case involving forwarding a
>   derived type to a base type.
>
> F.  **Should *not* forward arbitrary type conversions.** This use case
>   demonstrates how arbitrary conversions within a forward lead to
>   dangling reference run time errors.

The second overload enables cases B and C.

The paper goes on to provide examples of each use case, which are too lengthy to be repeated here.

**Update**

I've just run the "solution" of just the first overload through these 6 use cases, and this exercise shows that the second overload also enables use case F:  Should not forward arbitrary type conversions.

Comment: lol was halfway through typing out an answer linking to this paper -- glad you're here :-)