# Understanding of the implementation of std::forward since C++11

Tags: c++, move, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

(`constexpr` and `noexcept` are left out, since they seem irrelevant for the purpose of understanding how `std::forward` behaves.)

Based on my understanding of Scott Meyers' "Effective Modern C++",
a sample implementation of `std::move` in C++14 is the following

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) move(T&& param) {
  return static_cast<remove_reference_t<T>&&>(param);
}
```

Given the explanation of what a forwarding (or "universal") reference is, this implementation, I think, is pretty clear to me:

- the parameter `param` is of type `T&&`, i.e. an rvalue reference or lvalue reference (to whichever the type of the argument is), depending on whether the argument is an rvalue or lvalue in the caller; in other words `param` can bind both to rvalues and lvalues (i.e. *anything*); this is intended, since `move` should cast *anything* to rvalue.
- `decltype(auto)` is just the concise way to express the return type based on the actual `return` statement.
- the returned object is the same object `param`, casted to an rvalue reference (`&&`) to whatever the type `T` is, once its deduced referenceness is stripped off (the deduction is done on `T&&`, not on `⋯<T>&&`).

In short, my understanding of the use of forwarding/universal references in the implementation of `move` is the following:

- the forwarding/universal reference `T&&` is used for the parameter since it is intended to bind to anything;
- the return type is an rvalue reference, since `move` is intended to turn anything to rvalue.

It'd be nice to know if my understanding is right so far.

On the other hand, a sample implementation of `std::forward` in C++14 is the following

```
template<typename T>
T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& param) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(param);
}
```

My understanding is the following:

- `T&&`, the return type, <s>must be a forwarding/universal reference, since we want `forward` to return either by rvalue reference or by lvalue reference, hence type deduction takes place on the return type here (unlike what happens for `move`, where type deduction takes place on the parameter side)</s> is an rvalue reference to whichever template type argument is passed to `forward`;
- since `T` encodes the lvalue/rvalue-ness of the actual argument which binds the callers' parameter that is passed as argument to `forward`, `T` itself can result to be `actual_type&` or `actual_type`, hence `T&&` can be either an lvalue reference or rvalue reference.
- The type of `param` is an lvalue reference to whatever the type `T` is, once its <s>deduced</s> referenceness is stripped off. [Actually in `std::forward` **type deduction is disabled** on purpose, requiring that the template type argument be passed explicitly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947809/5825294)

My doubts are the following.

- The two instances of `forward` (two for each type on which is it called, actually) only differ for the return type (rvalue reference when an rvalue is passed, lvalue reference when an lvalue is passed), since in both cases `param` is of type lvalue reference to non-`const` reference-less `T`. Isn't the return type something which does not count in overload resolution? (Maybe I've used "overload" improperly, here.)
- Since the type of `param` is non-`const` lvalue reference to reference-less `T`, and since an lvalue reference must be to-`const` in order to bind to an rvalue, how can `param` bind to an rvalue?

As a side question:

- can `decltype(auto)` be used for the return type, as it is done for `move`?

Comment: `std::forward`'s second overload is `forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& param)`, and `remove_reference` does not remove cv-qualifiers

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, now I see that there are actually two overloads of [std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). I wander why only the former is mentioned in Meyers' book...

Comment: You forgot `constexpr` and `noexcept`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, are this two guys necessary to understand how `std::forward` works?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Only if you want to understand the parts they influence too. Or at least don't want to give a false impression, nor explain leaving them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forward` is essentially a machinery to conserve the value category in perfect forwarding.

Consider a simple function that attempts to call the `f` function transparently, respecting value category.

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) g(T&& arg)
{
    return f(arg);
}
```

Here, the problem is that the expression `arg` is always an lvalue regardless of whether `arg` is of rvalue reference type.  This is where `forward` comes in handy:

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) g(T&& arg)
{
    return f(forward<T>(arg));
}
```

Consider a reference implementation of `std::forward`:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template <class T>
constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>);
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

(You can use `decltype(auto)` here, because the deduced type will always be `T&&`.)

In all the following cases, the first overload is called because the expression `arg` denotes a variable and hence is an lvalue:

- If `g` is called with a non-const lvalue, then `T` is deduced as a non-const lvalue reference type.  `T&&` is the same as `T`, and `forward<T>(arg)` is a non-const lvalue expression.  Therefore, `f` is called with a non-const lvalue expression.
- If `g` is called with a const lvalue, then `T` is deduced as a const lvalue reference type.  `T&&` is the same as `T`, and `forward<T>(arg)` is a const lvalue expression.  Therefore, `f` is called with a const lvalue expression.
- If `g` is called with an rvalue, then `T` is deduced as a non-reference type.  `T&&` is an rvalue reference type, and `forward<T>(arg)` is an rvalue expression.  Therefore, `f` is called with an rvalue expression.

In all cases, the value category is respected.

The second overload is not used in normal perfect forwarding.  See [What is the purpose of std::forward()'s rvalue reference overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56361755) for its usage.

Comment: It might be worth including (a reminder) that there are three different possibilities for `T`.  (Also, since the question mentions it, the confusion about return types could be explained.)

Comment: I've not accepted the answer yet since I've not understood yet (my bad).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Maybe I can help you if you indicate precisely which part you don't understand.

Comment: @L.F., I'm basically making confusion between the rvalue/lvalue-ness of the argument to `forward<T>` and the rvalue/lvalue-ness of the argument to its caller. Indeed, regardless of `g`'s argument being an rvalue or an lvalue, the argument to `forward<T>` is an lvalue (`arg`), therefore the second overload of 'forward` should never be called (not in the three examples you mentioned, at least, since in all of them `forward<T>`'s argument has a name, `arg`), am I wrong?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Exactly, the second overload is not used in perfect forwarding.

Comment: @L.F., then I need a clarification about your third _If `g` is called with_, as there you say that _the second overload is selected_.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis My bad, I meant to say "`forward` is called with an rvalue" which is irrelevant.  I've updated the answer, hopefully it's clearer